# How to copy all child nodes as-is to resulting tree?

Tags: xslt

UPDATE (spoiler): This question is answered (see David Carlisle answere below) and it looks like a bug in XSLT implementation included in some versions in JRE (like it works in jdk but don't work on jre 1.6.0_20-b02 and not working at all at 1.6.0_31-b05). I logged a bug for that on Oracle site.

I almost there and in terms of functionality it works now. But I'm not happy with some parts of it, some of them (I believe) could be shorter. This is the question... For details see below

**This is an example of input xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<t1>
    <t2 a1="v1">
        <ot1 a2="v2" />
        <ot2 a3="v3">
            <t3 a5="v4">
                <ot1 a2="v5" />
            </t3>
        </ot2>
    </t2>
</t1>
```

**This is an example of expected result xml (see xslt file below, to get clue on whats-what)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<t1>
    <t2 a1="v1">
        <gt2 a="ot2" b="gtv1">
            <gt1 a="ot1">v2</gt1>
        </gt2>
        <gt2 a="ot2" b="v3">
            <t3 a5="v4">
                <gt2 a="ot2" b="gtv1">
                    <gt1 a="ot1">v5</gt1>
                </gt2>
            </t3>
        </gt2>
    </t2>
</t1>
```

**This is xslt I finally end up with (but not too happy).**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" version="1.0"
    exclude-result-prefixes="exslt">
    <xsl:output method="xml" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ot1|ot2">
        <xsl:variable name="thisResult">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="impl" />
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="exslt:node-set($thisResult)" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ot1" mode="impl">
        <ot2 a3="gtv1">
            <gt1 a="ot1">
                <xsl:value-of select="@a2" />
            </gt1>
        </ot2>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ot2" mode="impl">
        <gt2 a="ot2" b="{@a3}">
            <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
                <xsl:element name="{name()}">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()" />
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </gt2>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Question is: How to make this shorter?**

```
<xsl:for-each select="child::*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each>
```

**I tried following things, but in this case part of resulting xml will be lost (specifically attributes for the gt2 element will be lost)**

```
<xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
```

also tried

```
<xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
```

with no success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dimitre has shown an alternative strategy, but to answer the question in your original posting, the xsl:for-each is (apart from some namespace effects which do not show up here) equivalent to a single

```
<xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
```

and I get identical output if replace the xsl:for-each with that.

Your suggested replacement

```
<xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
```

is almost the same but picks up the white space nodes used to indent the source, so the output differs in white space.

You say

> (specifically attributes for the gt3 element will be lost)

but that coding change will not change attributes, and there is no `gt3` element in the example input or output?

Comment: Yes, it was a typo, just fixed it (it should be gt2) and also clarified example so multi-pass processing will make sense. Also I tried your suggestion, but that doesn't work for me. What XSLT processer are you using?

Comment: I use saxon 6.5 for xslt1 testing (otherwise I'd use saxon 9) if I run your stylesheet I get the same result as you bar whitespace, and if I replace the for-each by copy-of select="*" I get the identical (confirmed with diff) output as I get with your original stylesheet.

Comment: I'm using standard JRE builtin XSL Transformation engine. Looks like I hit a bug.

Answer (score 3):

> I need to define xslt transformation which able to perform so called
>   "multi-pass transformation".

**There is no need to use multi-pass processing here**.

**This short and simple transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="ot1">
  <gt1 a="ot1"><xsl:value-of select="@a2"/></gt1>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="ot2">
  <gt2 a="ot2" b="{@a3}"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<t1>
    <t2 a1="v1">
        <ot1 a2="v2" />
        <ot2 a3="v3">
            <t3 a5="v4">
                <ot1 a2="v5" />
            </t3>
        </ot2>
    </t2>
</t1>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<t1>
   <t2 a1="v1">
      <gt1 a="ot1">v2</gt1>
      <gt2 a="ot2" b="v3"/>
      <t3 a5="v4">
         <gt1 a="ot1">v5</gt1>
      </t3>
   </t2>
</t1>
```

**UPDATE**: The OP has updated the question with what he thinks needs multi-pass processing -- this still isn't true.

**Here is a short and simple solution to the new question, again in a single pass**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="ot1">
  <gt2 a="ot2" b="gtv{substring-after(name(), 'ot')}">
    <gt1 a="ot1"><xsl:value-of select="@a2"/></gt1>
  </gt2>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="ot2">
  <gt2 a="ot2" b="{@a3}"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied to the newly-provided XML source document:**

```
<t1>
    <t2 a1="v1">
        <ot1 a2="v2" />
        <ot2 a3="v3">
            <t3 a5="v4">
                <ot1 a2="v5" />
            </t3>
        </ot2>
    </t2>
</t1>
```

**again the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<t1>
   <t2 a1="v1">
      <gt2 a="ot2" b="gtv1">
         <gt1 a="ot1">v2</gt1>
      </gt2>
      <gt2 a="ot2" b="v3"/>
      <t3 a5="v4">
         <gt2 a="ot2" b="gtv1">
            <gt1 a="ot1">v5</gt1>
         </gt2>
      </t3>
   </t2>
</t1>
```

**UPDATE2**: As the OP is asking for refactoring of his current code, and particularly needs to express better this excerpt:

> ```
> <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
>   <xsl:element name="{name()}">
>       <xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()" />
>   </xsl:element>
> </xsl:for-each>
> ```

**here is one obvious refactorung -- just replace the above with**:

```
<xsl:apply-templates/>
```

**After this modification the complete code becomes**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" version="1.0"
        exclude-result-prefixes="exslt">
        <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
        <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

        <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="ot1|ot2">
            <xsl:variable name="thisResult">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="impl" />
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:apply-templates select=
            "exslt:node-set($thisResult)" />
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="ot1" mode="impl">
            <ot2 a3="gtv1">
                <gt1 a="ot1">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@a2" />
                </gt1>
            </ot2>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="ot2" mode="impl">
            <gt2 a="ot2" b="{@a3}">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </gt2>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**and when applied on the latest provided source XML document**:

```
<t1>
    <t2 a1="v1">
        <ot1 a2="v2" />
        <ot2 a3="v3">
            <t3 a5="v4">
                <ot1 a2="v5" />
            </t3>
        </ot2>
    </t2>
</t1>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
<t1>
   <t2 a1="v1">
      <gt2 a="ot2" b="gtv1">
         <gt1 a="ot1">v2</gt1>
      </gt2>
      <gt2 a="ot2" b="v3">
         <t3 a5="v4">
            <gt2 a="ot2" b="gtv1">
               <gt1 a="ot1">v5</gt1>
            </gt2>
         </t3>
      </gt2>
   </t2>
</t1>
```

Comment: Dimitre, thanks for the try! But don't get me wrong, "do I need the multi-pass processing" is not the question, I really need it. I edited the question to make this cleaner.

Comment: @Tornn: Why do you think that multi-pass processing **is necessary** for solving your updated question? Actually, it isn't necessary. Please, see the update at the end of my answer -- again a rather simple one-pass transformation solves this problem.

Comment: looks like you answering on question "Do I need multi-pass processing?". But this is not my question. I think I will edit it to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Tornn: Yes, it would be good removing the phrase "I need to define xslt transformation which able to perform so called "multi-pass transformation"."

Comment: Done. Unfortunately the issue is reproducible only when doing multi-pass processing :-(

Comment: @Tornn: I added a second update and there is a good refactoring.

Comment: Yes, I evaluated this approach, but decided to just copy inner contents because I want to minimize number of times each fragment will be processed. If I run apply-templates they will be applied to all child element twice: inside each specific template impl and when invoking multi-pass processing.

Comment: @Tornn: Yes, one can just use `xsl:copy-of select="node()"` and in this case it is equivalent to `xsl:apply-templates`. Using the latter is preferrable for easy extensibility. If in the future you decide that the descendants should undergo some specific processing and not just be copied as-is, then no modification of the existing code is necessary -- just add new templates matching the corresponding nodes. In XSLT using `xsl:apply-templates` is usually preferrable to having `xsl:for-each` or a unextensible `xsl:copy-of`.